# Прокомментировать код программы (Бинарное дерево)

Tags: c, бинарное-дерево, словари

Англо-Украинский словарь. Помогите прокомментировать. Я как бы понимаю что, где и как работает, но не думаю что мои комментарии получаться верными.
Заранее спасибо.

```
#include<stdlib.h> 
#include<string.h>
#include<stdio.h>
#include <locale.h>
#include<conio.h>

typedef struct words {

char eng[30], ua[30];
struct words *left, *right;
}tree;
tree *head=NULL;    //зануляем корень дерева

void place (tree *pnew, tree **addr); //разместить элемент в дереве 
void Add(char eng[], char ua[]);      // добавить элемент
char *Find(char eng[], tree *xz);     //найти элемент
void del_tree(tree* node);           //удалить дерево

int main(){

    getch();
    return 0;
 }

 void Add(char eng[], char ua[]){
 tree *q;                                      //создаем дерево
 q=(struct words*)malloc(sizeof(struct words));// выделяем по него память 
 q->left=NULL;                                 
 q->right=NULL;                           // зануляем левое и правое поддерево
 strcpy(q->eng,eng);                      // копируем строку eng в поле структуры eng
 strcpy(q->ua,ua);                       // копируем строку eng в поле структуры eng
 place(q,&head);                        // особо не понял -(( 
  }

 char *Find(char eng[], tree *xz){
 if (xz==NULL){                      // если корень дерева пуст то возвращаем Not found
        return "404 Not found";}
 int k=strcmp(eng, xz->eng);        //сравниваем строки если равны то 0 если нет то 1
 if (k==0)                           // если равна то
    return xz->ua;                 //возвращаем строку ua
 if (k>0)                          // если нет то
    return Find (eng, xz->right);  // идем в правую ветку
 else                              // особо не понял что else ?  
                                   //  `мы ведь рассмотрели "==" и ">0" 
    return Find(eng, xz->left);     //   идем в левую ветку
  }

 void place (tree *pnew, tree **addr){
 tree *root=*addr;          //создаем еще одно дерево и сохраняем
                            // в него корень *addr  (head)  
 if(root==NULL){           // если корень root пуст
 *addr=pnew;               // то корень *addr стает корнем pnew  
 return;
 }
 int k=strcmp(pnew->eng, root->eng);//сравниваем строки с корней pnew и root
 if(k==0){
    tree (pnew);                  // я не понял что оно делает
    return;
 }
 if (k>0)
    place(pnew, &root->right);     //  идем в правую ветку
 else                               // тоже самое.. зачем здесь else ?
    place(pnew, &root->left);     // идем в левую ветку
  }

 void del_tree(tree* node){  
 if(node != NULL){              // если корень не пуст 
 del_tree(node->left);         // идем в левую ветку и проверяем пуста ли она
 del_tree(node->right);        // идем в правую ветку и проверяем пуста ли она
 free(node);                   //освобождаем память корня
 }
  }
```

Comment: Предлагаю вам предоставить ваш вариант. А уж сообщество вас откорректирует. В итоге вы узрите некоторую разницу и не будет нарушения правил форума - работа за автора.

Comment: @smackmychi,  добавил мой вариант комментарий, надеюсь кто-то мне поможет.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ээх. Для начала, у вас неверная структура данных. Для слов короче 30 символов (большинства!) вы выделяете лишнюю память, а те, которые длиннее, просто крэшнут вашу программу. Это отдельная проблема.

Далее.

```
typedef struct words {
   char eng[30], ua[30];
   struct words *left, *right;
} tree;
```

Одна и та же структура называется то words, то tree — вы уж определитесь. По сути она, конечно, является узлом дерева, но в формальном определении бинарного дерева поддерево само по себе является деревом, так что название tree не такое уж и плохое.

---

```
void Add(char eng[], char ua[]) {
    tree *q; // этот код лишь объявляет указатель на дерево
    q=(struct words*)malloc(sizeof(struct words));
        // это лишь выделяет неинициализированную память нужного размера
    q->left=NULL;                                 
    q->right=NULL;
       // поддеревьев пока нет
    strcpy(q->eng,eng); // копирование данных, да
    strcpy(q->ua,ua);
    // в этой точке инициализиация готова, добавляем новое дерево как поддерево
    // в глобальное дерево head как поддерево
    place(q, &head);
  }
```

То, что добавление происходит в глобальную переменную — фе. Если вам понадобится маппинг в другом направлении, вы будете дублировать код?

---

```
void place (tree *pnew, tree **addr) {
    tree *root=*addr;
        // ничего не создаём, просто кладём указатель в переменную
    if(root==NULL) { // если дерево было пустое
        *addr=pnew;  // окей, теперь вместо него будет новое поддерево
        return;
    }
    // иначе у нас есть элементы, найдём, куда вставлять
    int k=strcmp(pnew->eng, root->eng);
    if(k==0) { // о, такой элемент уже есть в дереве
        free (pnew); // это не tree, это free
            // и кстати неправильно: а вдруг это дерево имеет поддеревья?
        return;
    }
    if (k>0) // если новый элемент больше элемента в корне
             // рекурсивно располагаем новый элемент в правом поддереве
        place(pnew, &root->right);
    else     // а если меньше, то в левом
        place(pnew, &root->left);
}
```

В целом: функция имеет инвариантом упорядочение дерева по возрастанию ключей, то есть это имплементирует простейший вариант дерева поиска (без балансировки веток).

---

```
char *Find(char eng[], tree *xz) {
    if (xz==NULL) { дерево пусто
        // идиотизм. как вы на уровне кода отличите случай найденного
        // от случая ненайденного ключа?
        return "404 Not found";
    }
    int k=strcmp(eng, xz->eng);
    if (k==0) // нашли строку в корне
        return xz->ua;
    if (k>0) // больше -> ищем в правом поддереве
        return Find (eng, xz->right);
    else // strcmp может вернуть и отрицательное число, бегом читать документацию!
        return Find(eng, xz->left);
}
```

Стандартный поиск в сортированном дереве.

---

Резюме: срочно восполнять пробелы по темам «указатели», «строки в C и операции с ними», «сортированное дерево» (оно же «[бинарное дерево поиска](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_search_tree)»).